# Angular JS - Control multiple views based on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

There is my *router.js*

```
$stateProvider.state("workarea", {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "/templates/workarea.html",
  requireLogin: true
}).state("workarea.shared", {
  url: "/workarea",
  controller: "workareaSharedCtrl",
  requireLogin: true,
  views: {
    "options": {
      templateUrl: "/views/options.html"
    },
    "workspace": {
      templateUrl: "/views/workspace.html"
    }
  }
}).state("workarea.user", {
  url: "/:username",
  controller: "workareaUserCtrl",
  requireLogin: true,
  views: {
    "options": {
      templateUrl: "/views/options.html"
    },
    "workspace": {
      templateUrl: "/views/workspace.html"
    },
    "comments": {
      templateUrl: "/views/comments.html"
    }
  }
})
```

This is the */templates/workarea.html*

```
<a ui-sref="workarea.shared">Shared</a>
<a ui-sref="workarea.user">Private</a>
<div ui-view="options" />
<div ui-view="workspace" />
```

When clicked on Shared, the views (options, workspace and comments) of workarea.shared should be loaded and when clicked on Private the views (options, workspace) of workarea.user should be loaded.

What am I missing here?

Comment: have u added  angular.module('App', ['ui.router']); ? and 
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ? DI's ?

Comment: Yes. This is a snippet. Dependencies are already handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKP9651U6VG7lwFfc6NQ?p=preview)

There are two issues. Firstly, **`<div>`** cannot be self closing, so this is a fix of the parent template

```
<div>      
  <a ui-sref="workarea.shared">Shared</a>
  <a ui-sref="workarea.user">Private</a>
  <!--
  <div ui-view="options" />
  <div ui-view="workspace" />
  -->
  <div ui-view="options" ></div>
  <div ui-view="workspace" ></div>
</div>
```

Also, controller belongs to view (even to each of them if more defined) not to state:

```
...
.state("workarea.shared", {
      url: "/workarea",
      // NOT here - controller belongs to view
      //controller: "workareaSharedCtrl",
      requireLogin: true,
      views: {
        "options": {
          templateUrl: "views/options.html",
          controller: "workareaSharedCtrl",   // here should be definition 
        },
        ...
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKP9651U6VG7lwFfc6NQ?p=preview)